# What does a "three-card-monte man" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns

I know what a [three-card-monte game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-card_monte) is, but I don't know what the author wants to say when he says "he wasn't a three-card-monte-man". I don't find any really intuitive connection between the game and the meaning in this context. Does that mean he wasn't a wizard?

> I was not long set before my friend returned. He looked pale and rather old, refused to hear of food, and called for tea.
> "I suppose all's up?" said I, with an incredible sinking.
> "No," he replied; I've pulled it through, Loudon - just pulled it through. I couldn't have raised another cent in all 'Frisco. People don't like it; Longhurst even went back on me; said he wasn't a **three-card-monte man**."
> "Well, what's the odds" said I . . .

From [*The Wrecker* by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter X, published 1892](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10)

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10

Comment: It means he wasn't good at or didn't enjoy playing three-card monte. English often uses that pattern: "To be honest, I'm not a cat person" means I don't like cats much.

Comment: He was not a *gambling* man, especially when the situation is rigged against him. Three card monte is a guessing game where the dealer uses sleight of hand to dupe the victim.

Comment: Longhurst didn't want to be associated with it and  he withdrew his support.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But what do you take the word "three-card-monte man" to mean in this context? How does the image of a three-card-monte man match the role of Douglas B. Longhurst. In my opinion it's a false picture or the three-card-monte man is just meant to be a wizard.

Comment: As pointed out by TimR, this is a colloquial reference by Longhurst meaning that he was averse to a risky gamble. In this reference, a "three-card-monte man" would be someone willing to take a risk at a game known for having few winners except the dealer/house.

Comment: The meaning is idiomatic - to be a [hobby/activity] + man = to be a man who is into doing a particular hobby/activity, or who is interested in such.  For example: I am not a trainspotting man (I'm not into trainspotting, it's not something I'm interested in).  He isn't  a gambling man (He is not into gambling). He is a pigeon man (His hobby is keeping pigeons), etc, etc.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it There is no dealer/house in three-card  monte. There's a guy on the street with a cardboard or wooden box which they use as the "table" for playing the three cards while onlookers gather and the dumb ones gamble. See it here: https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/10/17/nyregion/17crimescene/17crimescene-jumbo.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'*Three-card-Monte*' isn't just the name of a card game - it is a known *confidence trick*. The player never wins and is tricked into losing money.

On the surface, three-card-monte looks like a simple game of guessing the position of a specific card out of 3 dealt cards - a 1 in 3 chance of winning. However, in this trick, a third person working with the dealer gains an observer's confidence and tells them they know how the trick works and how to beat the dealer. They may say, for example, that the cards are marked or bent in some way so the dealer knows which is which. This encourages the person to play because they think they can win; however, the opposite is true, ensuring the player loses. For this reason, "a three-card-monte man" cannot be the same thing as "a gambling man", as anyone who knows what three-card-monte is knows that there are no favourable odds.

Your text is talking about failing to raise money ("*I couldn't have raised another cent in all 'Frisco'*"). By saying he wasn't a "*three-card monte man*" perhaps Longhurst is saying he wasn't prepared to raise money by immoral means. Alternatively, he may be referring to the scam because it has a 'guaranteed' return for those that run it. Looking at the wider text, it goes on to talk about "the odds", which could be the real chances of raising money properly.

Comment: That sounds good enough to me though I wouldn't say Longhurst wasn't prepared to raise money "by immoral means" but that he wasn't prepared to raise money - or to "conjure" money - by "whatever" means - "at all". That's why I suggested the word "wizard".

Comment: @philphil I don't understand what you mean by "wizard"... what does that have to do with the context? The expression "*to conjure up*" is almost always used flippantly as it suggests that something cannot be created out of nothing, or "out of thin air". Literal *three-card-monte* is a scam. It is a guaranteed win for those who run the scam, and immoral. If you don't think it is talking about morality then perhaps it is about the guaranteed return, because I looked at the wider context and the next line is asking about odds.

Comment: Doesn't a wizard conjure something sometimes? And a three-card-monte man can as well conjure money by his tricky skill in my opinion.

Comment: @philphil There's no such thing as wizards in real life. But there is such a thing as three-card-monte. So I'd say they are different analogies. One is about making money out of nothing, the other is about making money out of people by cheating them.

Comment: If you've ever been to NYC, you'd get this without any trouble. Just go to Times Square. Yes, it's a con. I can never figure out why people don't upvote correct answers. See it here: https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/10/17/nyregion/17crimescene/17crimescene-jumbo.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp

Comment: @ Astralbee - I've seen wizards conjure up bunnies out of a hat actually, haven't you?? When I say "wizard" I mean it, of course, figuratively in this context

Comment: @philphil Sure, and that is also a kind of trick - unless you believe magic is real. You're talking about stage magicians. A 'conjuring' trick is a particular type of stage magic trick where something *appears* to be brought out of thin air, like a rabbit from a hat, for example. But the rabbit already belongs to the magician. When we use "conjured up" as a metaphor it tends to be in reference to 'real', supposed magic - the ability to create something out of nothing. We have other metaphors for producing something we secretly had stashed away - like "up my sleeve" or "pull it out of my a**".

Comment: @ Astralbee - "When we use "conjured up" as a metaphor it tends to be . . . - the ability to create something out of nothing": That's exactly what I think Longhurst wants to express when he says he wasn't a three-card-monte man.

Comment: @philphil but scam artists running a three-card-monte scam aren't conjuring money from nothing - they are taking it from people. It seems to me to be a very different metaphor, which is why I answered as I did.

Comment: @ Astrabee - Thank you very much. Yes, in fact, you are right, and that's why I have said the metaphor isn't correct there. I said in the OP  "I don't find any really intuitive connection between the game and the meaning in this context,"and in a comment I said "How does the image of a three-card-monte man match the role of Douglas B. Longhurst? In my opinion it's a false picture or the three-card-monte man is just meant to be a wizard" - or say magician.

Comment: @ Astralbee - And then you say "@philphil "There's no such thing as wizards in real life. But there is such a thing as three-card-monte. So I'd say they are different analogies. One is about making money out of nothing, the other is about making money out of people by cheating them." ---You are opening a vicious circle, I'm afraid :). By the by, Longhurst isn't a fraud or scammer, he is just the chief of a ring at the Exchange.

Comment: @philphil Final word on this tangent which has nothing to do with your original question. Imagine you ask a conman, a stage magician, and a real magician to each raise $1000. The real magician makes $1000 appear out of thin air - nobody loses, you gain. The stage magician has to find $1000 of his own money to make it look like it appears - he loses. The conman runs a three-card-monte scam, tricks the $1000 out of other people - the marks lose. These are all very different results. Your text mentions the three-card-monte. I see that as a metaphor for raising money dishonestly.

Comment: @ Astralbee - *Your text mentions the three-card-monte. I see that as a metaphor for raising money dishonestly* - As I said, you are perfectly right. But the wider context doesn't yield or convey that, because Longhurst isn't a conman. That's why I criticize this comparison or metaphor of the authors. It doesn't really work there in my opinion. Maybe others are of a different opinion. But thank you very much for discussing the different meanings and results in this regard - I understand this.

Comment: To sum up: Three-card-Monte isn't a card game people play, it's a **rigged shell game**. It's entertaining trickery played on passersby. Saying Loudon wasn't that type says he wasn't a trickster. Above all, it is unexpected here that English learners will second-guess Stevenson in "I criticize this ... metaphor of the author."